# Global Maven Repository for Gitlab builds inside docker container

Tags: maven, docker, gitlab

I am running a Gitlab installation inside a docker container. The builds itself are also running in docker containers. As I build mostly Maven artifacts the dependencies need to be downloaded for each build, which produces a lot of bandwidth. I was able to reduce this at least for builds of the same artifact using the provided cache, but this works only for consecutive builds.

Is there a way of maintining a global maven repository outside the Gitlab installation where all build containers have access to, so the dependencies need to be downloaded only once at all?

Comment: You can have nexus in a long running docker instance and tell your Maven dockers about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest running an internal Maven repository server and tell your dockerized Maven builds to use that.  Several exist, I have found Nexus to work well with our needs (a merged view of Maven Central and an internal repository) and can be easily started with

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

You can then have a very simple settings.xml file in your dockerized Maven build:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>local-nexus</id>
            <name>Local Nexus</name>
            <!-- Host external IP number -->
            <url>http://172.17.0.1:8081/repository/central/</url>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <!-- applied to the image we were using, may not apply to yours -->
    <localRepository>/usr/share/maven/ref/repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```

I believe the 172.17.0.1 IP-number was the first assigned by Docker in that setup. For orchestrated builds it will most likely have a real name.

You will still download half the internet, but just from the internal repository when fully populated.

Comment: Having a dedicated Nexus installation for this seems quiet overblown, but nevertheless it seems to work. Going out of the Server and directly in again does not increase the network traffic of the server. Thanks!

Comment: @svenkubiak Well, simpler solutions probably exist but this is what the Maven architects wants us to do.  In general I've found that moving decisions and configuration and  out of the Maven client (like asking Nexus to provide merged views of upstreams repositories) is the best solution in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the cache live outside the containers on a host and mount that as a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) into the containers that need them. For the build containers, simply mount the host folder holding the cache into the container where the maven cache is expected (usually `/home/<user>/.m2/repository`)

For example, to mount `/path/on/host` from the host into `/path/in/container` inside the container, use the following command:

```
docker run -v /path/to/host/folder:/path/in/container buildImage:latest
```

The cache need to live outside of the build containers as you want it reused between builds.

EDIT: As [Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbj%C3%B8rn-ravn-andersen) pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172377/global-maven-repository-for-gitlab-builds-inside-docker-container/54172974#comment95176906_54172974) the suggestion above could lead to problems in case multiple build containers are running in parallel as Maven assumes ownership of the .m2 directory. In that case it might be better to configure the build containers to use an artifact repository manager like Nexus running in a separate container. The Nexus container can then mount the repository form disk in order to detach it from the lifecycle of the container.

Comment: Don't use it as .m2.  Maven expects to own this directory so  it should not be shared to avoid race conditions.  You can use it as a read-only file repository.

Comment: Good point @Thorbjørn, I have updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen How would a read-only local maven repository update its dependencies?

Comment: @danielorn I am not sure you can configure the docker containers for the build via gitlab in that way, but looking into it.

Comment: @svenkubiak You can have a prepopulated local file repository which the local maven instance can pull from.  It still needs its own .m2/repository folder to store artifacts; both cached and downloaded (which you want to avodi)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen So if updated dependencies are available the need to be manage by hand, correct?

Comment: I dont understand your question.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen E.g., I have a project with 58 external dependencies (e.g. Undertow, Jackson, etc.), which are regularly updated. If I have a prepopulated local maven repository where I want to have cached and download, how dooes one track changes in a prepopulated local maven repository?

Comment: @svenkubiak In my experience that can be handled with an external long lived build that downloads the needed artifacts and then can provide a read-only export to the docker processes.  Given the size of your project I would have a local long-running Nexus instead.  I'll write this up in an answer.